# How to send the send regitration request to GCM server from app server to register the device?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I know we can get the registration id from GCM server in GCM client android app.
we can send the message to GCM client app from app server though GCM server.
I want to send the device registration request from app server to GCM server rather than through client app? is it possible?
if yes what information i have to send to GCM server to register the device?
on which basis GCM server registers the devices?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible because registration is just supported on the three client apps defined in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration). Tokens can only be generated using the library that google has provided for each platform.